# Extract habituation effect with randomized trials

Tags: panel-data

I want to find an orientation effect in my data. I did a response time experiment with 2 conditions (congruent and incongruent response mapping [answering a-left-b-right vs. b-left-a-right]) ... Now I want to demonstrate with statistical means that the congruent condition has an initial advantage (faster responses), but after some trials of orientation, the participants habituate to the incongruent response mapping and catch up with the participants in the congruent condition.

Now there's a problem: of the 32 trials, 16 were of very different stimuli (high distance) and 16 of quite similar stimuli (low distance) AND the trials were presented in randomized order.

I was thinking, maybe it would need to be something in a long data format and maybe something with regression, but I just can't figure it out.
Please help me.

(My sample is balanced with an N=96, but it's only an exploratory afterthought, so I don't need to worry about the power too much ...)

Comment: Is it as simple as mapping the *average* response time over the 32 trials for each condition? Regardless, I think it would be tough to decompose habituation from other effects such as learning or even fatigue.

Comment: Well, it's a basic ANOVA design of response mapping x distance, so I already did the analysis with means. For further investigation, I would like to drop the mean-approach and investigate the development of response times over trials (which are randomized and with two different conditions).

Comment: As far as the other effects - nevermind. I would just like to find that after a few trials, response times drop more for the incongruent condition than for the congruent condition.

Comment: I'm not talking about the ANOVA, I'm suggesting an XY visualization where the x-axis is the sequence of trials 1 to 32 and Y is the average response time.

Comment: oooooooooh :D that's smart! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! :D ..... I suppose I can't do any test of significance on that?

Comment: You've done the ANOVA. Would a sequential ratio test by trial make sense?

Comment: I'll google this test :D ... for now thank you very much! Even if it won't fit, I'll still have the graphs and I bet they'll look good :D

Comment: The test makes sense to me...but do with it what you will....Good luck!